# Record multiple variables into array upon clicks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have a menu of buttons and am trying to record which buttons are selected. Multiple buttons can be selected at the same time. Currently, I'm only able to record individual buttons selections into individual arrays, but I am trying to loop through which buttons are selected to put all the variables in one array.

I hope to end up with an array like this: ["A", "C", "D"] if those buttons are selected. I hope to record the array when the user hits the done button.

Does anyone have advice on what I'm doing incorrectly? Many thanks in advance!

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #done {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="buttonGallery">
      <div id="done">
        <p>done</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let $buttonGallery = $("#buttonGallery");
      let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
      let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];

      myList.map(function(letter, index) {
        let $button = $("<div></div>")
          .addClass("buttons")
          .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
          .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
          .on("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
          })
          .on("mouseleave", function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
              $(this).css("background", "transparent");
            }
          })
          .on("click", function() {
            $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            let clicked = [];
            let syms = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
            console.log(syms);

            for (let n = 0; n < syms.length; n++) {
              clicked = [];

              if (!clicked.includes(syms[n].textContent)) {
                clicked.push(syms[n].textContent);
                console.log(syms[n].textContent);
              }
              console.log('click', clicked);
            };

          })
        $("#done").before($button);
      });

      $("#done").on("click", clearColor);

      function clearColor() {

        $(".buttons").css({
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        });
        $(".buttons").removeClass('selected');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: declare this `let clicked = [];` globally and see currently you are declaring it inside your on click event that's the reason its not working

Comment: @Swati, thanks for you comment — I tried your suggestion to declare globally and get 3 arrays if I click on 3 buttons, e.g., ["A"], ["A", "C"], and ["A", "C", "D"]. Can you explain why it outputs three arrays rather than just the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `clicked` globally as suggested in comments and could use the spread operator to deduplicate your array:

```js
let $buttonGallery = $("#buttonGallery");
let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];
let clicked = [];

myList.map(function(letter, index) {
  let $button = $("<div></div>")
    .addClass("buttons")
    .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
    .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).css("background", "transparent");
      }
    })
    .on("click", function() {
      $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
      $(this).addClass('selected');

      let syms = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
      let selected = [...syms].map(el => el.textContent)
      console.log("selected", selected);

    })
  $("#done").before($button);
});

$("#done").on("click", clearColor);

function clearColor() {

  $(".buttons").css({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  });
  $(".buttons").removeClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2px;
}

#buttonGallery {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 155px;
}

#done {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonGallery">
  <div id="done">
    <p>done</p>
  </div>
</div>
```